# @Backoff multiplierExpression

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

Good day!

I'm trying to adjust customized backoff delay for retry in 1h - 3h - 6h - 12h ... (x 2) in my Spring Boot kafka application.

What can I do now is only to set multiplier as "2" and get 1h - 2h - 4h ... delay as backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3_600_000, multiplier = 2) in @RetryableTopic parameters.

I found backoff element "multiplierExpression" in Spring docs but unfortunately can't find anything how to describe this expresson to work properly.

I would be grateful for any hints or links.

Comment: Have you been able to try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

**MultiplierExpression** helps you write a expression which can be evaluated by Spring on run-time (after the first failure, but before first retry).

Here is an example for it

```
@Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "@runtimeConfigs.maxAttempts",
        backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "@runtimeConfigs.initial",
         maxDelayExpression = "@runtimeConfigs.max", multiplierExpression = "@runtimeConfigs.mult"))
public void service() {
    ...
}
```

in this case `multiplierExpression` is being picked from a bean named runtimeConfigs.

> Starting with version 2.0, expressions in @Retryable, @CircuitBreaker, and BackOff can be evaluated once, during application initialization, or at runtime. With earlier versions, evaluation was always performed during initialization (except for Retryable.exceptionExpression which is always evaluated at runtime). When evaluating at runtime, a root object containing the method arguments is passed to the evaluation context.

> Note: The arguments are not available until the method has been called at least once; they will be null initially, which means, for example, you can't set the initial maxAttempts using an argument value, you can, however, change the maxAttempts after the first failure and before any retries are performed. Also, the arguments are only available when using stateless retry (which includes the @CircuitBreaker).

More details can be found in [official documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry?tab=readme-ov-file#declarative-retry)

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`multiplierExpression`

> Evaluates to a value used as a multiplier for generating the next
> delay for backoff. Overrides multiplier().

Also you can take a look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry#readme)

You can inject value from configuration properties as with `@Value`
annotation (e.g. `@Backoff(multiplierExpression = "${retry.maxDelay}")`) or make some calculation with `#{}` expression utilization (e.g. `@Backoff(multiplierExpression = "#{1.1 * 5}")`)

Hope this helps :)